# Русские буквы в пути к файлу C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio, url, кириллица

Если пытаюсь прочитать где только английские символы в пути файл читается  но если где русские ошибка открытия.
например

```
ifstream in("C:\\\\folder\\1.txt");
```

откраивает отлично но

```
ifstream in("C:\\\\Пака\\1.txt");
```

Уже ошибка, как исправить

Когда то сталкивался с таким но тогда нашел решение исправил и забыл, сейчас вновь проблема.

для получения пути использую **glfw**, drad and drob технологию. Для открытия mp3 с помощью **bass**. Но не думаю что ето важно, проблема более глобальная.

Comment: ifstream in("C:\\\\Пака\\1.txt"L); ?

Comment: Вообще зачем использовать полный путь? Взять рядом с EXE положить и всё. А уж внутри папки приложения никто не заставляет именовать папки не английскими буквами.

Comment: Фишка именно в том что файл будит открыт пользоватилем программы

Comment: "C:\\\\Пака\\1.txt"L так не пойдет так как у меня не константа, в пути а переменная ПУТЬ полученный от пользователя я не могу всунуть в такую конструкцию ("C:\\\\Пака\\1.txt"L) переменную вместо текста

Comment: в примере нет ничего про ввод пользователем

Comment: Да так я не хотел несколько сотен кода бросать "для получения пути использую glfw, drad and drob технологию. Для открытия mp3 с помощью bass. Но не думаю что ето важно, проблема более глобальная."

Comment: Добавление L поможет в данном случае. Быть может кто-то решится даже написать почему. ifstream in(path); можно написать тогда без 100 строк.

Comment: У меня такая конструкция видает ошибку

Comment: BASS_ChannelStop(channel);
 sample = BASS_SampleLoad(false, paths[i]L, 0, 0, 1, BASS_SAMPLE_MONO);

Comment: L это спецификатор строки. К переменной его не применить.